# How to check if your website is trending?

Tags: analytics, social-media, api, feeds

I am building a admin stats dashboard for my website.   I would like to show on it an indication when an article from my site is trending (gone viral) on Facebook or Twitter.

My understanding is that Facebook and Twitter have trending feeds. How can I programatically access these trending feeds so that I can check to see if my website is listed on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a formulae. You take the number of hits in period X and the period before X, and if it increased, it's trending.

Ofcourse, this is very simplistic. You should expand this to a few periodes, in which it should grow, and it should be over some threshhold (because going from 1 to 3 hits in 300% increase, but not trending).

The length of a period, or the number of periods you need to check varies on the type of website and number of visitors/activity (high activity = short periods).

Also, take the creationdate into account, the last-activity-date, etc. Think of all the thinks that could be relevant, and form it into the formulae. There is no default function for that.

Comment: Thank you @Martijn. Do I need to develop something similar to Google Robots to search through websites or is there a handy website which has an open API which does something like this? My understanding on how it works has been cleared up, however how to get the data, I still do not understand.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your question, I thought you ment `like FB`, not `on FB`. You should check their api, you can get views and events from it

Comment: I do mean like Facebook, does Facebook only show what is trending from their websites view? I thought they scoured the internet for trending words. It appears I have the whole concept wrong...

Comment: Maybe you should check out google trends, I believe that might be of some assist